# File is not a valid web archive error on downloading html as .doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

I am using jquery.wordexport.js and FileSaver.js to convert and export a part of a page as a Word Document. The downloaded document gives "File is not a valid web archive" on Office 2011 on Mac. Any ideas what the issue might be here?

It is a simple function and as far as I can tell, no edits were needed to make this plugin work.

```
$("#dat_save_download").click(function (event) {
    $(".doc-margins").wordExport();
})
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bvd8jdrw/2/)

Comment: so save whatever did download to disk, then load that into a text/hex editor and see what you DID receive.

Comment: What am I looking at here? I am not sure how to check for errors in the hex editor.

Comment: look for anything that doesn't look like zip data. e.g. if something's screwing up and sending out some html, then your .docx won't be a zip file, it'll be some html, or error text.

Comment: It is a .doc, not .docx.

Comment: Sorry, this file is not a Ms Office OLE2 Compound File (PPT/DOC/XLS)

I get this error message when I scan the .doc file withe OfficeMalScanner. The error is not displayed for any other .doc file that opens up in Mac.

Comment: then whatever is being downloaded is not an office file, or is corrupted somehow.

Comment: @AspiringCanadian Did you ever figure this out? Also came across this error with Word 2011 for Mac

Comment: @Nathan, sadly, no.